# syntax search over a string with sas

Tags: sas

Got the following example

[image]

I'm trying to know if any part of string in the column `nomvar` in table tata does exist in col1 in table toto and if yes, give me the definition using col2.

For I2010,RT,IS-IPI,F_CC11_X_CCXBA, I would have in the column `intitule` "yes,toto,tata,well"

I thought about using a `proc sql` with an insert and a select but I have two tables and I would need to do a join.

In the same time, I thought to have everything in one table but I'm unsure if it is a good idea.

Any suggestions are welcomed as I'm deeply stuck.

Comment: What if nomvar contains a value that doesn't exist in col1? Do you want to leave it out of intitule? And does the order of intitule matter?

Comment: Bonjour Laurent, toto does work as a dictionary therefore everything that exist in the table tata should have a match in col1. But let's assume that there is something missing in col1, then intitule should be only with an empty space between 2 commas or one comma.

Comment: And yes, the order does matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is all structured like this (you're looking at the different strings in between `.` characters) I would think the easiest way is to normalize `TATA` (splitting by `.`) and then doing a straight join, then (if you need to) transposing back.  (It might be better to leave it vertical - very likely you would find this more useful structure for analysis.)

```
data tata_v;
 set tata;
 call scan(nomvar,1,position,length,'.');
 do _i = 1 by 1 while position le 0);
    nomvar_out = substr(nomvar,position,length);
    output;
    call scan(nomvar,_i+1,position,length,'.');
 end;
run;
```

Now you can join on `nomvar_out` and then (if needed) recombine things.

Comment: Hi Joe, when you mean splitting by `.`, do you mean changing the `,` by a `.` ? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the picture is hard to read but it looked like it was separated by '.'.  What I ultimately mean is taking each value separated by whatever and writing those values out to separate rows, so `abc.def.ghi` becomes `abc`, new row `def`, new row `ghi`.

Comment: Hi Joe, it was separated by comma. I'm going to change that to a comma and do a test.

Answer (score 3):

The SAS data step hash object is a nice way to do this.  It allows you to read the Toto table into memory and it becomes a lookup table for you.  Then you just walk the string from the Tata table using the scan function, tokenize, and lookup the col2 value.  Here is the code.

By the way, turning table Tata into a structure like Toto and performing join is a perfectly rational way to do this, too.

```
/*Create sample data*/
data toto;
   length col1 col2 $ 100;
   col1='I2010';
   col2='yes';
   output;

   col1='RT';
   col2='toto';
   output;

   col1='IS-IPI';
   col2='tata';
   output;

   col1='F_CC11_X_CCXBA';
   col2='well';
   output;
run;

data tata;
   length nomvar intitule $ 100;
   nomvar='I2010,RT,IS-IPI,F_CC11_X_CCXBA';
run;

/*Now for the solution*/
/*You can do this lookup easily with a data step hash object*/
data tata;
  set tata;
  length col1 col2 token $ 100;
  drop col1 col2 token i sepchar rc;

  /*slurp the data in from the Toto data set into the hash*/
  if (_n_ = 1) then do;
     declare hash toto_hash(dataset: 'work.toto');
     rc = toto_hash.definekey('col1');
     rc = toto_hash.definedata('col2');
     toto_hash.definedone();
  end;

  /*now walk the tokens in data set tata and perform the lookup to get each value*/
  i = 1;
  sepchar = ''; /*this will be a comma after the first iteration of the loop*/
  intitule = '';
  do until (token = '');

     /*grab nth item in the comma-separated list*/
     token = scan(nomvar, i, ',');
     /*lookup the col2 value from the toto data set*/
     rc = toto_hash.find(key:token);
     if (rc = 0) then do;
        /*lookup successful so tack the value on*/
        intitule = strip(intitule) || sepchar || col2; 
        sepchar = ',';
     end;

     i = i + 1;
  end;
run;
```